# Storing variables upon calling Higher Order Function

Tags: python, higher-order-functions

if I want to call a function with an argument, without using anything fancy like declaring nonlocal variables or creating a list, how do I store my argument each time I call my function so that it 'remembers' the previous arguments that I have called previously?
My idea is as follows:

```
# stac(x) is a function that returns another function (nested) or itself. 
>>> stac(4)(5)(6)(4)(6)(7)(8)(3)(0) 
# if 0, prints the previous numbers that was called most recently to first call 
3
8
7
.
.
4
```

Some thing similar what I have in mind is detecting whether if there is a repeated argument in stac(x), such that every time it prints out x if x matched one of the previous arguments.

```
# stac(x) is a function that returns another function (nested) or itself. 
>>> stac(1)(2)(3)(4)(1)(3)(5)(7)
1
3
# since 1 and 3 is repeated
```

My thoughts on how to approach the idea is that we return a function defined in the current frame so that, if our argument in the new frame meets a condition (or not) it checks the previous frames down to the frame when we first call an argument. Though I am not sure if that works. If someone has an idea of how to implement it I would be grateful!

Comment: Does zero clear the stack?

Comment: I'm not sure what that means, in my head I just think if my current argument is 0 then it returns the previous calls and print the 'previous' arguments along the way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need something that's accessible to the namespace of each of the objects you return, otherwise you won't be able to print all the prior arguments. So yeah, you'll probably want a list or deque or some other mutable container. But you can make it local to the first function call:

```
def stac1(n):
    s = []
    def k(n):
        if n == 0:
            print(*s, sep='\n')
            return s
        s.append(n)
        return k
    return k(n)
```

Your second example can be implemented in a similar manner but with a set instead of a sequence:

```
def stac2(n):
    s = set()
    def k(n):
        if n in s:
            print(n)
        else:
            s.add(n)
        return k
    return k(n)
```

While this technically uses a shared container, each call to `stac` instantiates its own, so there is no global shared state. At the same time, neither function will behave correctly if it's split:

```
>>> a = stac1(1)(2)
>>> a(3)(0)
1
2
3
[1, 2, 3]
>>> a(0)
1
2
3
[1, 2, 3]
# desired [1, 2]
```

```
>>> b = stac2(1)(2)
>>> b(5)(1)
1
>>> b(5)
5
# desired nothing
```

A naive approach would be to pass around an immutable sequence/frozenset, or at least a copy, e.g., as a second default argument to `k`. That's quite slow and wasteful though, at least for `stac1`. You could use a linked list instead, so each branch after the split got its own sequence without having to duplicate the parents:

```
from functools import partial

def stac1b(n):
    def k(p, n):
        if n:
            return partial(k, [n, p])
        s = []
        while p:
            n, p = p
            s.append(n)
        s.reverse()
        print(*s, sep='\n')
        return s
    return k(None, n)
```

`stac2` is a little tougher to deal with. On the one hand, a linked list approach just like the one shown for `stac1b` is possible. The drawback is that a full linear search must be performed for each added element. On the other hand, passing around copies of sets seems wasteful, but makes the lookup much faster. Since duplicate elements don't require a copy, I'll show the latter option:

```
def stac2b(n):
    def k(s, n):
        if n in s:
            print(n)
            return partial(k, s)
        return partial(k, s | {n})
    return k(set(), n)
```

Comment: is there anyway that without assigning mutable container, 's' locally am I able to achieve the same thing? like say I declare the variable in our outer return statement, and update it with the inner return statement. Thanks

Comment: @treebeard. Yes, and I see the need for it now.  Will update

Comment: @treebeard I'm on mobile, so can't test, but this update should do it

Comment: I will try to make sense out of the complexity, thanks !